# How to design neural network ouput to segment or label an image with some overlapping same class object instances

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

Just for topic, e.g. I want to segment every pencil in these overlapping pencils.
There I think to use a softmax classifier to segment pencils and background.
Since pencils are same class,but need to segment individual instance.
Is it a right way to assign binary connections to every pixels pair,0 means the two pixel node are different instance,1 means they are same instance,
and build a graph to find the strongly connected components for segment pencils?
Here's [some overlapping pencils](http://www.featurepics.com/StockImage/20080829/color-pencils-stock-photo-872231.jpg)